# Writing file to CD/DVD process

Tags: software-recommendation

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS..
I want to burn a disk .
I followed the following procedure....

1. Insert Blank DVD
2. Open the File location.
3. Right click on the file...Select the option Write
   to Disk..
4. After completion of Write , I get one small window..
   That contain following lines...

Write to Disc ( 100% done)
Burning image to DVD..
Creating image checksum..

These process takes a long time..
So could I cancel Creating image checksum ...
Is it affect my cd/dvd quality??????
and any alternative procedure that take less time..

Please give me suggestion...

Thank you..

Answer (score 8):

It won't affect the already burnt cd/dvd, checksum creation is just a means to verify the contents. You can hit cancel if you like.

Comment: Thank you for immediate reply..Its really taking a long time than write Disk....

Comment: It is designed to verify the burnt content against your source file(s). If you feel confident about the integrity of the disc, you can cancel it. I'm sure Brasero has an option to disable checksum generation.

Now, can you mark my response as the answer, please?